# How to switch RTS rs232 with minimum delay after byte transfer?

Tags: c++, serial-port, writefile

I am trying to write a program to read device parameters. There is a peculiarity in connection with it. The communication protocol with it is a byte-by-byte data transfer. Moreover, in order to send a byte, I must set the RTS line to a high logical level and with a minimum delay after sending a byte, I must set a low logical level of the RTS line. The device itself does not control the RTS and CTS lines in any way (such a strange circuit design). Now I'm trying to send at least one byte to the device and get a response from it.

I send it using the writeFile function. I am not an experienced programmer, and in my understanding, after the end of writing, writeFile should return the value "true", which for me is a condition for transferring the RTS line to a low logical level. Apparently the value "true" is returned ahead of time and the RTS line is switched ahead of time, due to which the byte is cut off. If I try to add a delay of at least 1ms, the RTS switches as early as 15ms after the byte is transmitted, which is not allowed. All this can be seen on the oscilloscope. 5ms is the maximum allowed time for switching RTS after sending a byte. Please, tell me how to solve this problem.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define hard_pause while(1){}

using namespace std;

HANDLE hSerial;

void port_set()
{
    LPCTSTR sPortName = "\\\\.\\COM4";
    hSerial = ::CreateFile(sPortName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
                                    0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    if(!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "getting state error\n";
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate    = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize    = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits    = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity      = NOPARITY;
    dcbSerialParams.XonLim      = 1;
    dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;

    if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "error setting serial port state\n";
    }
}

void com_write()
{
    EscapeCommFunction(hSerial, SETRTS);
    char data[1] = {0x81};  
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(data);  
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;  
    BOOL iRet = WriteFile(hSerial, data, dwSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    if(iRet == true)
    {
        EscapeCommFunction(hSerial, CLRRTS);
    }

}

 void com_read()
 {
    DWORD iSize;
    char sReceivedChar;
    while(true)
        {
        ReadFile(hSerial, &sReceivedChar, 1, &iSize, 0);  
        if(iSize > 0)  
            cout << sReceivedChar;
    }
 }

int main()
 {

    while(true)
        {
    EscapeCommFunction(hSerial, SETRTS);
        com_write();
                com_read();
        Sleep(1000);    
    }

    hard_pause;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*with a minimum delay after sending a byte, I must set a low logical level of the RTS line*" -- This cannot be performed efficiently from userspace because your program executes asynchronously with the device driver and hardware I/O. Hence the poor results that you're getting. (I'm assuming that you're using a multitasking OS, rather than baremetal code on a microcontroller.)  Proper method is to do this in the device driver, where an interrupt can be used to notify when the byte has been transmitted (i.e. the Tx register is empty).

Comment: This hopeless protocol was designed by somebody that wants to sell you their solution.  Resistance is futile.

Comment: If you intend to persue a userspace solution, then abandon the use of (fixed) timers. You need to obtain the Tx state from the driver.

Comment: I see that you're setting `dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE` so why can't you use `dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE` and allow the hardware to do its job of setting the RTS  line for you?